# Is it possible to update a DoubleAnimation.FromProperty without restarting the entire animation?

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard

I'm not hugely familiar with a lot of WPF yet, so if this query betrays some clear misunderstandings I'd appreciate them being pointed out.

What I'm trying to do (for good or ill) is synchronise a `DoubleAnimation.FromProperty` with the actual width of a StackPanel containing/running the animation.

I originally tried doing this with data binding, e.g.

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(anim, 
   DoubleAnimation.FromProperty, 
   new Binding {Source = panel, Path = new PropertyPath(ActualWidthProperty)});
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Although I can bind a text box to the From property and see that it's changing, the animation continues to run from the initial value. Is this anything to do with story board freezing? (which I know nothing about but have just heard of)

Then I thought why not stop and restart the story board (turn it off and on again!), changing the FromProperty in the meantime, by handling the `StackPanel.SizeChanged` event. Something like this :

```
void panel_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (myStoryBoard != null && myStoryBoard.GetCurrentState(panel) == ClockState.Active)
    {
        myStoryBoard.Stop(panel);
        foreach(var child in myStoryBoard.Children)
        {
            var anim = child as DoubleAnimation;
            if (anim == null) continue;
            anim.From = panel.ActualWidth;
        }
        myStoryBoard.Begin(panel, true);
    }
}
```

This works, but, of course, it starts the animation from scratch each time the panel is resized. What I'd prefer is to be able to resume the animation from the point it was interrupted but with a new FromProperty. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a lot easier than you think. The cool thing about Animations in WPF and Silverlight is that they can be relative to the current situation. The only thing you need to do to create a relative animation is creating for example the DoubleAnimation with To filled in but do NOT fill in the From.

Example below is to animate the opacity of a stackpanel from the current value to 1:

```
<DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0: To="1" 
     Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" 
     Storyboard.TargetProperty="StackPanel.Opacity" />
```

EDIT1:
Make the animation loop back to its original value without using the from and loop forever

```
<Storyboard AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:2" 
                        To="1"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="StackPanel.Opacity"
                        />
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: I don't think this really solves the problem. I need to set the From because I want the animation to cycle. In this case, it should cycle from the right edge of the panel to out of view on the left side.